# input event with if condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use eventlistener to detect the rows in textarea, but when I press backspace the if condition doesn't work. How can I improve this?

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  // Get the scroll height of the textarea
  let taHeight = $('textarea').scrollHeight;
  let numberOfLines = Math.floor(taHeight / 16);
  height(numberOfLines);

})

function height(numberOfLines) {
  console.log(numberOfLines);
  if (numberOfLines == 2) {
    $('textarea').removeClass('row-2 row-3').addClass('row-2');
  } else if (numberOfLines == 3) {
    $('textarea').removeClass('row-2 row-3').addClass('row-3');
  } else {
    $('textarea').removeClass('row-2 row-3');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: the snippet is throwing this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ta is not defined`

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `scrollHeight` property. I've added a `console.log` so you can see the value of `numberOfLines` in `height`. it's always `NaN`, because `$('textarea').scrollHeight` is always `undefined`, and `undefined / (anything)` is `NaN`.

Comment: let taHeight = $('textarea')[0].scrollHeight;

Comment: Separately, `scrollHeight` isn't a great way to get the number of lines (scrollbars mess it up), and assuming `16` is the height of a line is problematic at best. What definition of "height" are you really looking for? It may be complicated to get it, depending on what it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The height function is to define the height of textarea. And I put the [demo here](https://codepen.io/penny289/pen/JjrGQGe?editors=0010). The textarea should expand or shrink by the numberOfLines.